# Is it possible to use 'return' and 'out' the same time?

Tags: c#, parameters, return, out

I have a method `GetSelectedServices()` which returns Selected Nodes from a Tree List,
Expecting to return with the same method selected nodes and all Nodes i tried to add an `out` parameter.

But when I call this method i'm supposed to give the out parameter and so the returned list with selectedNodes is masked, and i cannot have it.

**My Method**

```
internal List<__ServiceInfo> GetSelectedServices(out List<__ServiceInfo> lstAll)
{
    List<__ServiceInfo> lstSelected = new List<__ServiceInfo>();
    List<__ServiceInfo> lstA = new List<__ServiceInfo>();

    foreach (TreeListNode node in this.tlServices.Nodes)
    {
        if (node.Checked)
        {
            var service = this.tlServices.GetDataRecordByNode(node) as __ServiceInfo;
            lstA.Add(service);

            if (service != null)
            {
                lstSelected.Add(service);
            }

            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (TreeListNode subNode in node.Nodes)
                {
                    if (subNode.Checked)
                    {
                        service = this.tlServices.GetDataRecordByNode(subNode) as __ServiceInfo;
                        lstA.Add(service);

                        if (service != null)
                        {
                            lstSelected.Add(service);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    lstAll = lstA;

    return lstSelected;
}
```

**The way I call the method**

```
public bool HasValidModel()
{
    List<__ServiceInfo> lstAll = new List<__ServiceInfo>();
    //here I get all nodes
    var allServices = this.GetAllServices(out lstAll);

    List<__ServiceInfo> lstSelected = new List<__ServiceInfo>();
    //but how to get the list from  ""return lstSelected"";
}
```

thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: So basically, "all" contains everything in selected and then a bunch of `null` entries?

Comment: It appears that `GetSelectedServices` is returning the same list for both "all" & "selected" - assuming that `service` is never `null`. If there are any nulls then your results are even more weird.

Comment: Your program violates section 2.4.2 of the C# specification; **it is a worst practice to write a program that has two consecutive underscores in an identifier unless you are on the implementation team for the framework or the compiler.**

Comment: @Eric: Is it a worth practice in general? If so, why do you guys have this convention internally? Just curious. I assume this is because it makes it harder to know how many underscores to type for a variable.

Comment: @JoanVenge: We want you to avoid ever putting two underbars in an identifier because we reserve the right to make breaking changes in the future by creating new keywords that have two underbars in them. For example, `__arglist` is an undocumented keyword of C#. If we ever decided to make a feature of C# that reserved `__ServiceInfo`, the code in this question would be broken upon recompilation. For your own safety you should avoid making any identifier that has `__` in it.

Comment: Thanks Eric, didn't know this. Cheers for the info. I dislike underscores anyway.

Comment: OK Eric Lippert , i'll refactor this. I didn't know about 2.4.2 and their intentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use two variables, like this:

```
List<__ServiceInfo> lst;
List<__ServiceInfo> lstSelected = GetSelectedServices(out lst);
```

The 'return'ed object is now referenced by `lstSelected`, while the `out`ed object is referenced by `lst`.

Answer (score 4):

You've already got two variables, although you're initializing one of them unnecessarily. Just use:

```
public bool HasValidModel()
{
    List<__ServiceInfo> lstAll;
    var selectedServices = this.GetAllServices(out lstAll);

    // Now use lstAll and selectedServices
}
```

Personally I don't really like using out parameters much, and would look for an alternative design if possible, but that's a separate matter. (I'd separate out finding *all* services from selecting some of them.)

Answer (score 3):

The way you implemented the `return` and the `out` parameter seems to be fine. But the call is wrong. @Ken's answer points in the right direction.

However the logic in the `GetSelectedServices` method is odd. The only difference between a "selected" service and a "regular" service is that a "regular" service is `NULL`. Which leads to the result that the `allServices` list is a collection of NULLs plus the selected services. Which makes no sense in my opinion.